# How to write select query that excludes results with the status of "Expired" if there is already a valid status linked to the same subject?

Tags: sql, sql-server

| empid | Subject | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Emp01 | S1 | Valid |
| Emp01 | S1 | Expired |
| Emp01 | S2 | Valid |

If an employee ID is selected as 'Expired', and there is already a valid status associated with it,  display the valid status only in the result.

Please help me find a solution to get the desired result.

```
SELECT empid, subject 
FROM t1 
GROUP BY empid, subject
```

| empid | Subject |
| --- | --- |
| Emp01 | S1 |
| Emp01 | S2 |

This returns 2 rows.

```
SELECT empid, subject 
FROM t1 
WHERE (status = 'Expired')
GROUP BY empid, subject
```

| empid | Subject |
| --- | --- |
| Emp01 | S1 |

This returns just a single row.

What I need is a result of 0 rows when I select the status 'Expired'.

```
SELECT empid, subject  FROM t1 WHERE (status = 'Valid')
GROUP BY empid, subject
```

| empid | Subject |
| --- | --- |
| Emp01 | S1 |
| Emp01 | S2 |

This also returns 2 rows.

Comment: "What I need is a result of 0 rows" Why? Can you show sample sample data which returns something? It's hard to understand otherwise.

Comment: Why is `c#` and `asp.net` added in the tags? Did you mean to tag `sql` instead?

Comment: Sorry, I was working on the Asp.net platform to get the SQL command.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a condition with exists

I added one row where the condition fits

```
CREATE TABLE A
    ([empid] varchar(5), [Subject] varchar(2), [Status] varchar(7))
;
    
INSERT INTO A
    ([empid], [Subject], [Status])
VALUES
    ('Emp01', 'S1', 'Valid'),
    ('Emp01', 'S1', 'Expired'),
    ('Emp01', 'S2', 'Valid'),
    ('Emp01', 'S3', 'Expired')
;
```

```
SELECT
   [empid], [Subject], [Status]
FROM A A1 WHERE [Status] = 'Expired'
  AND NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM A WHERE [empid] = A1.[empid] 
  AND [Subject] = A1.[Subject] AND [Status] = 'Valid')
```

| empid | Subject | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Emp01 | S3 | Expired |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/wVX08IUW)